# Showing legend valueText in XYChart using AmCharts

Tags: javascript, legend, amcharts

I have an XYChart implemented using AmCharts 3, I wanna to show valueText next to legend labelText. I tried to set `"valueText": "[[value]]"` in legend object, and `"legendValueText": "[[value]]"` in graph object, but none of them worked.
Full of case code can be found in https://codepen.io/safaasalem/pen/VwLqWLa

Please help on how to make it work.

Comment: Legend `valueText` is not supported in v3 XYCharts. Sorry.

Comment: Is it supported in AmCharts 4?

Comment: Nope, same limitation applies in a dual value axis setup.